# How to prevent that somebody can follow you on GitHub?

Tags: github

On GitHub it is possible that people can follow you. I wonder whether it is possible to prevent that some people can follow me.

I checked whether I can click on an "unfollow" button, but that is only possible if I am following somebody.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is only possible if you add a user to the blocked list in github.

https://github.com/settings/blocked_users

source: https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account